# How can I use an "if statement" to check if what a user has inputted is the same as text on another file? (Python)

Tags: python, file

I am making something that is password protected and to stop you from being able to see the password just by looking at the code I put it on another file and I am trying to have the code check if what was input is the same as the password on the other file

I have a variable that reads the file with the password and a different variable that reads what the user input and when I make an if statement that checks if the user input variable is the same as what is on the other file but if I input the correct password to the variable that gets checked against the other file it doesnt say I put the right one in

Comment: my code: pas = open(".config/password")
while True:
  ps = input("What is the password? ")
  if ps == pas:
    clrCon()
    print("Hello :)")

Comment: Put code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: You need to call `pas.read()` to get the contents of the file as a string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), then edit your post to put the code in the post itself. Then make sure to describe the problem clearly (using complete sentences with proper punctuation), and **ask a question**, starting with a question word like "how" or "why" and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `pas = open(".config/password")`, what do you think that does?

Comment: Also, you should use `.strip()` to remove a trailing newline from the file contents.